# Abort trap with SWIG for C++ and Lua

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I've been recently working for the first time with SWIG in order to create new Lua modules from C++. I'm working under Mac OS (El Capitan). Let me explain what I do step by step:

1) Create .cpp file

```
int myAddition(int x, int y)
{
  return (x+y);
}

int mySubtraction(int x, int y)
{
  return (x-y);
}
```

2) Create the interface file (.i):

```
%module test
%{
   extern int myAddition(int x, int y);
   extern int mySubtraction(int x, int y);
%}
 extern int myAddition(int x, int y);
 extern int mySubtraction(int x, int y);
```

3) Create the wrapper and a shared library with the following commands:

```
 swig -c++ -lua test.i
 g++ -I/usr/local/include -c test_wrap.cxx -o test_wrap.o 
 g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
 g++ -bundle -L/usr/local/lib/ -llua test_wrap.o test.o -o test.so
```

4) I create a .lua file to test the new module:

```
require("test")
print(test.myAddition(10,40))
print(test.mySubtraction(20,40))
```

The output of the script is the following:

50.0
-20.0
lua(21360,0x7fff7b739000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10d86b998: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

If I change the script into the following:

```
require("test")
print(test.myAddition(10,40))
print(test.mySubtraction(20,40))
os.exit()
```

, everything seems to be fine:

[Output] 50.0 -20.0

Do you spot any problem, or is it really necessary to call os.exit() once the script is done?

EDIT: Lua version is 5.3.2. The output of *g++ -Wl --verbose -bundle -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -llua test_wrap.o test.o -o test.so*
is the following:

Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -bundle -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -o test.so -L/usr/local/lib/ -llua test_wrap.o test.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

Comment: Could You please clarify Lua version being used and post output of `g++ -Wl,--verbose -bundle -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -llua test_wrap.o test.o -o test.so` ? Found [this issue](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-01/msg00274.html)@Lua mailing list, related to wrong linkage.

Comment: Sure. Lua version is 5.3.2. I'll edit the post to answer both questions. I had seen the issue of the link you provide, but I wasn't sure whether the problem was actually the same (related though).